# In Ubuntu 18 installation, setting manual ipv4 address shows IP_ADDR/SUBNET error has host bit set

Tags: ubuntu

While trying to install Ubuntu server 18.4.01, when I am trying to configure manual IPV4 address, I am getting an error that:

> 192.168.1.50/24 has host bits set

I am unable to proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 21):

Found the solution. I was entering wrong values. I have to provide the value in the `Subnet` section in following format:

> 192.168.1.0/24

And the IP address in `Address` field.